# Understanding Python formatting

Tags: python

I am very new in Python programming, so I just learn it from LPTHW by Zed Shaw.
In section 8, called "Printing, printing", there is some code, but one part I don't understand:

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"

print formatter % (1, 2, 3, 4)
print formatter % ("one", "two", "three", "four")
print formatter % (True, False, False, True)
print formatter % (formatter, formatter, formatter, formatter)
print formatter % (
    "I had this thing.",
    "That you could type up right.",
    "But it didn't sing.",
    "So I said goodnight."
```

What is formatter? He writes it as a `numbers`, `letters`, `True` or `False` and as `formatter` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, formatter is just a string. A '%' in a string marks the start of a specifier.

There are a large number of specifiers in python and you can see them [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html)

In your print statements, you are just giving the values for the specifiers mentioned in formatter variable.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks dude

It's 2:22 am, so I got all morning to work it out

Answer (score 0):

In this case, that is only a tip for you put a formatted value into string. see more in docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Comment: I get it now, thanx